# HttpGet method route in .netCore to get list in query and work with api gateway

Tags: .net-core, routes, aws-lambda, httprequest, aws-api-gateway

I have an HttpGet method in C# .netCore v6 that is defined as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<GetUsersResponse> GetUsers([FromQuery] List<string> ids, [FromQuery] string[]? requestedFields, [FromHeader(Name = "x-trace-id")] string traceId)
```

The main route in the controller (which contains this method) is:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/users")]
```

I want to be able to access this method by the route: `https://localhost:port/api/users?ids=123&ids=321`

When I ran this locally - it works perfect but when I run this microservice on my AWS lambda function and tries to access this method from the AWS APIGatway I get the following error:

```
{
    "errorType": "NullReferenceException",
    "errorMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "stackTrace": [
        "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
        "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
        "at lambda_method2(Closure , Stream , ILambdaContext , Stream )",
        "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.Invoke(Stream lambdaData, ILambdaContext lambdaContext, Stream outStream) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 145",
        "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0(InvocationRequest invocation) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/HandlerWrapper.cs:line 55",
        "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line 176"
    ]
}
```

Which basically says that the APIGateway didn't even succeed on entering the method.
How can i define properly the route to my method so I'll be able to call her from the APIGatway?

Note:
1.When i tries to call the method within the lambda i call the APIGateway from Postman.
2.If I set the method route to be: `[Route("get-users")]` then if I call the method with the URL `https://localhost:port/api/users/get-users?ids=123` it works, but if I do not want to add anything after `users` in the route.

Comment: What [integration type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-integration-types.html) are you using? We need more info on how your API gateway is configured.